# How to upload a picture from rest client in Codeigniter and save file name to database?

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest

I want to upload picture from rest client to server and save file name at the same time to database using codeigniter. but it only save the other data, the picture and filename didnt upload at all

here is api model.

```
function save_confirm()
{
    $config['upload_path']   = './upload/';   
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';
    $config['overwrite']     =  TRUE;    
    $config['max_size']      = '100000';
    $config['max_width']     = '100000';
    $config['max_height']    = '100000';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    $this->upload->do_upload("pict");
    $data = array('upload_data'=>$this->upload->data("pict"));      
    $file_name = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];  

  $data = array(
    'id_booking'      => $this->input->get('id_booking'),
    'username'        => $this->get_username_by_user_token(),
    'transfer_date'   => date('Y-m-d'),
     'pict'           => $file_name
    );
  $this->db->insert('confirmation',$data);
  return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

api controller code

```
    public function confirm_get(){
    $get_confirm = $this->api_model->save_confirm();

    $data = array(
        'meta' => array(
            'status'  => 200,
            'message' => "OK",
            "code"    => 9
        ));
    $this->response($data,200) ;
}
```

please help, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have your `do_updoad_data()` wrong see changes below must set parent variable i.e `$file_data = $this->do_upload->data();`

```
function save_confirm()
{
    $config['upload_path']   = './upload/';   
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';
    $config['overwrite']    =  TRUE;    
    $config['max_size']      = '100000';
    $config['max_width']     = '100000';
    $config['max_height']    = '100000';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);


    if ($this->upload->do_upload("pict") == true) {

    $file_data = $this->do_upload->data();
    $file_name = $file_data['file_name'];

    // http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

    // Examples
    $file_type = $file_data['file_type'];
    $file_path = $file_data['file_path'];
    $full_path = $file_data['full_path']; 

    $data = array(
    'id_booking'       => $this->input->get('id_booking'),
    'username' => $this->get_username_by_user_token(),
    'transfer_date'   => date('Y-m-d'),
     'pict'     => $file_name
    );

    $this->db->insert('confirmation',$data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();

  } else {

    // return false;

  }

}
```